# Using "extern" in C through Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, extern

I have two .c files.

The first contains this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count;
extern void write_extern();

main(){
    count = 5;
    write_extern();
}
```

The second contains this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int count;

void write_extern(void) {
    printf("count is: %d\n", count);
}
```

My goal is to print "5" by doing this.  I understand that there is a way to do it using Command Line, but I can't find instructions on how to do it through Eclipse for C/C++ in the C language.

Comment: This should work fine if both files are linked into a single program. What errors are you getting? Are both files in the same eclipse project? Note: Using only `main()` isn't really good style (no return type, missing parameters).

Comment: Standard warning: The signature of `main` is non-standard, presenting undefined behaviour. The declaration of `write_extern` is also non-compliant,as it is relying on K&R-style signature.

Comment: OK thanks. I figured out i just didn't know how to put the files under the same project